# Why is this program not polymorphic?

Tags: java

In the follwoing program I am trying to overload a method by passing paramaters, but the out put for both methods is the same

```
 public class A 
    {

    int a = 11;
    int b = 20;
    static int c = 0;

        public void A1(){

            c = a+b;

        }

        public void A1(int a,int b){

            c = this.a+this.b;

        }

        public static void main(String[] args){

            A a = new A();
            a.A1();// this should give 31
            System.out.print(c);
            a.A1(3,46);// this should give 49
            System.out.print(c);
        }
 }
```

OUTPUT : The output for both is 31.

Even though I am trying to overload , the out put for both is same.

Comment: System.out.print(c); could not access c otherwise

Comment: `c = this.a+this.b;` this line is problematic. you are not using the parameters passed to the method.

Comment: this has nothing to do with polymorphism

Comment: `c` should be private (and not static) and accessed with getter.

Comment: You should also avoid calling your classes and variables a, b and c.

Answer (score 2):

In

```
public void A1(int a,int b){
    c = this.a+this.b;
}
```

You are ignoring the parameters you are passing to your method, and add the instance variables `this.a` and `this.b` instead.

Change it to

```
public void A1(int a,int b){
    c = a+b;
}
```

in order to add the two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
public void A1(int a,int b){
    c = this.a+this.b;
}
```

you are using `this` prefix. It means that you use your class fields, not your parameters. Parameters here will be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

You are using keyword `this`.

This should get you expected result.

```
  public void A1(int a,int b){

        c = a+b;

    }
```

Here `int a` and `int b` hide the instance fields `a` and `b`. By using `this` keyword you were fetching those hidden fields.